# do not respond to subscribe() selectively in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using Redux in my application. One my page, I have 5 controls which subscribe to the store. But in case of certain specific actions, I do not want 2 controls to respond to the change. How can I handle this situation.

I looked at this link https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/580 but I could not find anything like `store.getState().lastAction`.

What is the best way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a flag in your state saying if you should update your control or not. One of the base principle of Redux is to not allow client to know how the store is updated. You should only respond to state changes, whatever has changed the state.

But I don't really understand why you have to handle store changes by hand in react ? You should consider using `react-redux`.

**Edit**

As pointed in comments, if you need to do some side effects when dispatching actions, you should use some redux middleware such as [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), [redux-observable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable), [redux-loop](https://github.com/redux-loop/redux-loop). The simplest one for beginner is, I think, [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk). It allows you to dispatch a simple function that will be executed and that will be able to also dispatch other actions.

However, to trigger a side effect for each action and being able to filter by action type, please see [redux-tap](https://github.com/markdalgleish/redux-tap) as indicated in comments by @Brandon.

Comment: I am suing `react-redux`. But assume when I say `store.subscibe(funcOne)`, `store.subscibe(funcTwo)`, `store.subscibe(functhree)`. What I want is when action == 'ActionOne', I only want to call funcOne for all other actions, I want to call all the three functions. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @Emrys Myrooin is correct. You shouldn't be responding to actions, but to state changes. If you do need side effects, consider using a middleware for that, such as [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), [redux-observable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable), [redux-loop](https://github.com/redux-loop/redux-loop) and others.

Comment: @Lucas: I am not responding to actions. Rather, I rely on subscribe(). When an action is dispatched, which ever functions I have registered with subscribe() get called. What I am saying is, in certain cases, I do not want some callback functions to be executed, even though they are subscribed.

Comment: @OpenStack Ok. We understand. But it's an anti-pattern... Take a look to redux-saga, it allows you to do some side effects for each actions dispatched. You will be then able to filter out what action should call which function.

Comment: redux-tap is also good for running side effects when certain actions are applied

Comment: @Brandon I have never used redux-tap ! Does it allow to have juste a catch all that calls a function except for one action for exemple ? Because it's what he is asking :-)

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin it is a middleware that will call your function for every action, which means you are a single `switch` or `if` statement away from executing action-specific logic

Comment: @Brandon Great it's the perfect library for his use case, I will edit my answer. Thanks !

Comment: @OpenStack Is your question answered ? If it is please accept the answer. If not, close your question or say us what is wrong.